# Github Action: Gradle does not generate or save APK

Tags: android, github, gradle, continuous-integration, github-actions

Hi I am really new with Github Action and Gradle. What I am trying to do is write a github action script that creates a new gradle build every time there is a push to the branch. The current script looks like this:

```html
name: Android CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ Main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ Main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
    - name: set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'adopt'
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x ./gradlew
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build
    - name: Upload APK
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2.2.3
      with:
        name: app
        path: ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

When running the script, it works great with no reported errors:

[Output of script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4Z7D.jpg)

However, the apk is not generated. thus, when trying to upload it as an artifact, a warning is given as the apk file does not exist. To see if my implementation is correct, I tried the equivalent locally and it works successfully with the apk generated. So, why won't Github Action save the generated apk into the github branch? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using `app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`without the `./`?

Comment: yes it still does not generate an .apk. If i manually added an .apk file in that specific directory, the .apk file will be uploaded as an artifact. So the problem definitely relates to Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed! I am writing this for reference. For context, I am building an android app through unity. In the repo, I have the Gradle project settings generated through Unity's export function. Another important component of this problem is that the gradle files are not in root. Thus, when referencing gradle files, I have to specify the directory to run gradlew build (i.e. file1/file2/gradlew build. If you are having an issue similar to mine, this may apply to you:

1. In your local.properties file, change the directory of android sdk to the following path: sdk.dir=/usr/local/lib/android/sdk
   I got the path from the following link: https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/environment-variables-full-list-github-actions
2. In github action run any gradle types of file through root. This can be done by moving to the root directory of the gradle files and running it as root (i.e. cd file/file2 && ./gradlew build)

Hopefully these steps might help someone with a similar issue to mine.